# Replacing Values in Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to replace values in a pandas `DataFrame` based on logic that determines if a value is a above or below a certain threshold with N/A?`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range(start='2015-12-31',
                                       periods=13,
                                      freq='M'),
               'val': [1, 10, 25, -1000, 45, 66, 99, 88,128, 256,512,1024, 2048]}).set_index('date')
```

So I would like to replace any value > abs 10 with N/A

Comment: Sorry are you asking just to replace values that are not equal to 10?

Comment: Replace values **greater or less** than 10 not equal would be `!= 10`

Comment: So is my updated answer correct?

Comment: Your first answer was correct.  With the abs()

Comment: It was changed before I had chance to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask to set just the rows that meet the boolean condition, additionally you can use [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) to test if the value is +/- 10:

```
In [107]:    
df.loc[df['val'].abs() > 10, 'val' ] = np.NaN
df

Out[107]:
             val
date            
2015-12-31   1.0
2016-01-31  10.0
2016-02-29   NaN
2016-03-31   NaN
2016-04-30   NaN
2016-05-31   NaN
2016-06-30   NaN
2016-07-31   NaN
2016-08-31   NaN
2016-09-30   NaN
2016-10-31   NaN
2016-11-30   NaN
2016-12-31   NaN
```

Comment: Seems to me that @toasteez meaned 'not equal' not 'less than 10 and bigger than 10'. Special syntax :)

Comment: @knagaev `!=` is **Not Equal** and `<>` is **greater than or less than**.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference as I don't see how you wouldn't get the same result using `!=` here?

Comment: I wanted all values that were in the set of numbers range  -10 to +10 only

Comment: that was not clear in your question, you should've posted what the desired result was

Comment: @EdChum I'm glad that all was clarified :)